# YouTube no longer allows user to set resolution

Tags: youtube

Recently (as of mid August 2015) YouTube has changed its UI so that it automatically sets the resolution to the window size (typically 360) and no longer gives the user the option to choose their resolution. Even if the user goes to full screen, it still stays at 360.

How can control the resolution of the video and watch at HD full screen?

I would prefer a solution that does not involve installing software or add-ins.

Comment: No still it's there by default it will be in that resolution if you select auto, still you can set maximum resolution which is available for that video which you are watching by clicking on that 360p like mentioned below.

Comment: I noticed the same thing when using Firefox on Windows XP - can't change the resolution. However, I could change the resolution in Chrome on Windows XP. On Windows 7, it was fine for both browsers.

Answer (score 6):

You're wrong in claiming so. It is actually available, but, you have to click on that 360p to get several other options. Even in the full-screen mode, the same set of options are available.

[image]

Clicking on the pointing arrow next to the 360p, opens up a set of resolutions.

[image]

If you're having any problem with that, I suspect it might have something to do with that video(video might be available only in 360p resolution) OR else you might be doing it wrong.